Can anyone figure out this specific type of brick?
It is from Acme Bricks but I am unsure on the specific type. I tried Home Depot and Lowe’s but they do not carry it. It is 9.5Lx2.5W.



It appears to be a broken piece, so the 2.5W is real but the 9.5L is not. It might be structural clay tile rather than brick, too. Related but not the same. And far harder to come by now than 70-plus years ago when it was a very common product.

Looks to be a type of brick made decades ago .  Not something standard.
Try Brick It.  They have a large assortment of brick types.
